# Dirty flag in Knockout ViewModel not working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm facing issues while adding dirty flag to my viewmodel.
This Viewmodel is used to populate a grid. I'm using this in MVC project to populate a grid.
ViewModel is in the following format:

```
        function obejctDataToSchema(object) {

        return {

        "identifiers": {

        "id": object.userId.toString(),

        "name": object.userName

        },

        "expand": {

        "CredentialHolderAssignedCredential": [

        {

        "authFactor": {

        "pin": object.userCode

        },

        "expand": {

        "CredentialAssignedPermission": [

        {

        "identifiers": {

        "id": object.authorityLevel

        }

        }

        ]

        }

        }

        ],

        "CredentialHolderAssignedToPartition": [

        {

        "identifiers": {

        "id": 1

        }

        }

        ]

        }

        }

        };

        function User(data) {

        this.userId = ko.observable(data.userId);

        this.userName = ko.observable(data.userName).extend({ required: true });

        this.partition = ko.observable(data.partition);

        this.userCode = ko.observable(data.userCode).extend({ min: 1000, max: 9999 }, { required: true });

        this.authorityLevel = ko.observable(data.authorityLevel);

        this.zwaveDoorLock = 0;

        return this;

        }

        function userDefaults() {

        return new User({ userId: 0, userName: '', partition: true, userCode: '', authorityLevel: 0, zwaveDoorLock: 0 });

        }

        function schemaDatatoObject(data) {

        return new User({

        userId: parseInt(data.identifiers.id),

        userName: data.identifiers.name,

        partition: data.expand.CredentialHolderAssignedToPartition[0].identifiers.id,

        userCode: data.expand.CredentialHolderAssignedCredential[0].authFactor.pin,

        authorityLevel: data.expand.CredentialHolderAssignedCredential[0].expand.CredentialAssignedPermission[0].identifiers.id

        });

        }

        var usersModel = function (intData) {
        var self = this;
        self.authorityLevels = authorityLevel;
        self.zwaveDoorLock = zwaveDoorLock;
        self.selectedItem = ko.observable(userDefaults());
        self.operation = ko.observable();
        self.count = ko.observable(0);
        self.list = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(intData, function (item) {
        return schemaDatatoObject(item);
        }));

        self.update = function () {

        // check if valid

        if (self.errors().length > 0) {

        self.errors.showAllMessages();

        logger.logError("Correct All Errors Before Saving", "", "", "error");

        return;

        }

        else {

        debugger;

        var item = self.selectedItem();

        var jsItem = ko.toJS(item);



        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.list(), function (item) {

        return item.userName() === jsItem.userName;

        });

        if (match) {

        logger.logError("User" + " " + jsItem.userName + " " + "already exits", "", "", "error");

        return;

        }

        saveData(item)

        $("#editTemplate").css("display", "none");

        $("#displayAdd").css("display", "none");

        }

        };

        function saveData(item) {

        var jsItem = ko.toJS(item);

        jsItem.partition = +(jsItem.partition);

        $.each($("#userGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data, function (index, userData) {

        if (_.find(self.authorityLevels, function (e) { return e.name == userData.authorityLevel; }) != null)

        userData.authorityLevel = _.find(self.authorityLevels, function (e) { return e.name == userData.authorityLevel; }).id;

        });

        var objectData = { ObjectTypeId: objectTypeId, EntityIdentifier: jsItem.userId, EntityValue: JSON.stringify(new obejctDataToSchema(jsItem)), ObjectTypeName: "User" };

        doAjax.request({

        contentType: 'application/json',

        dataType: 'json',

        type: "POST", url: "SystemConfig/SaveEntityData", data: JSON.stringify({ accountNumber: accountNumber, objectData: objectData }), callbackSuccess: function (returnData) {

        if (returnData) {

        if (self.operation == 'edit') {

        $("#editTemplate").css("display", "none");

        var htmlString = $("#editTemplate")[0];

        $.each(self.list(), function (idx, elem) {

        if (elem.userId() === jsItem.userId) {

        self.list.remove(elem);

        return false; 

        }

        });

        $("#settingsHeader").append(htmlString);

        }

        self.list.push(new User(jsItem));

        if (self.list().length < maxUsers) {

        createNew();

        }

        }

        }

        });

        }
```

Please help me out and suggest how can I add a dirty flag to this.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of dirty flag do you want, to track changes on the model? If so, check how i've done here: http://jsfiddle.net/david_freire/3HZEu/3/

Comment: Your viewmodel is very simple. My viewmodel is completely different. Could you pls update the fiddle with my viewmodel?